# Generate dynamic link in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to generate a link on the private area of my site that points to an external page with some params that must change in function of the user and the moment the user sees that link.

I'm using the PHP Code Snippets plugin, and I think I have defined the snippet correctly, returning the URL instead of echoing it, etc...

The problem is that I don't know how to make the href attribute to be the value that this snippet returns (which is, as I said, the URL). Could you help me please?

Example of the snippet:

```
function gen_link($data) {
$REMOTE_AUTH_URL = "http://example.com";
 .... do some calculations on data 
return "$REMOTE_AUTH_URL?$query";
} 
$user = get_user_id(); 
return gen_link($user);
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your snippet.

Comment: It's something like:
function gen_link($data) {
.... do some calculations on data
return "http://"$result
}

$user = get_user_id();
return gen_link($user);

Comment: Please just edit your question.

Comment: I've already done, thanks.

Comment: `echo "<a href="' . gen_link( get_user_id() ) . '">Link to some generated link based on the user ID</a>;`

Comment: Note: Your PHP is invalid.  This line `return "http://"$result ` needs to be modified to either `return "http://{$result}";` or `return "http://" . $result;` - lastly, you should be using https, not http :)

Comment: Fixed in the question.

Comment: @cale_b this is not working. The result is a link to gen_link(id), but gen_link is treated as text, not actually executed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `PHP Code Snippets` plugin expects, but your function has some obvious error which maybe is the case if the plugin catches everything and silence all error.

Or it's just a syntax error in your example:

```
return "http://"$result
```

Should be

```
return "http://" . $result
```

(or a template string in PHP which pattern I don't remember at the moment (`"http://{$result}"`)?

Comment: The example is baddly written, but there are no syntax errors. I will fix it now so there is no more confusion.

Comment: The problem, I think, it's in the page code. How can I force href to be the result of this function?

Comment: I don't think I can help you without seeing the actual code and some docs about the wordpress plugin.